# Verifying the time complexity of selection sort by counting the number of comparisons

Tags: java, sorting, selection

I'm trying to verify that selection sort is O(n^2) by counting the number of times numbers are being compared in my array. I'm using an array of 20 numbers so I know I should be getting somewhere around 400, but with the current placement of my counting variable I'm only getting around 200 comparisons being counted. Here is the code for the selection sort I am using:

```
public static void selectionSort(final int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int minElementIndex = i;
           
            
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                swapCount++;
                if (arr[minElementIndex] > arr[j]) 
                {
                    minElementIndex = j;
                    
                    
                    
                }
            }
            
            if (minElementIndex != i) {
                
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[minElementIndex];
                arr[minElementIndex] = temp;
                
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```

The swapCount variable is being used to track the comparisons and I've tried moving it around everywhere I could think of, but I can't get a count nearly as high as I'm expecting when I print the total swapCount at the end. Where exactly in the code should swapCount be to track all the comparisons?

Comment: Should be 190, right?  You're only comparing where `j > i`, but it's still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: 190 would make sense with what I've been getting as a result, but I thought to be O(n^2) there had to be more comparisons for an array of 20 numbers. How is 190 correct? I don't understand.

Comment: No, `O(n^2)` doesn't mean `=n^2`.  It just means that as `n` gets larger, the growth in time required is either quadratically related to the growth in `n`, or approaches being quadratically related.

Comment: Ahh, okay, thanks for the explanation. I thought it was guaranteed to be n^2 no matter what.